Magento 2 : Unable to process binding "click: function(){return openMyList }" in Magento 2
I'm trying to open Custom Module List when I click on the button in the header. For this I tried the below code.
In header.phtml file added x-magento-init code
 <div id="my_list-div" data-bind="scope:'my_list'">

    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#my_list-div": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app":{
                    "components":{
                        "my_list":{
                            "component": "ABCSolutions_MYList/js/list",
                            "template": "ABCSolutions_MYList/list"
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    </script>
 </div>

and html code is
<div class="container">
.........
</div>

and the js is
    define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'mage/url',
    'mage/storage',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'loader',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
], function (ko, Component, urlBuilder,storage, $, modal, loader, confirm) {
    'use strict';

    let enterePressEvent = false;

    return Component.extend({

        defaults: {
            template: 'ABCSolutions_MYList/list',
        },

       
        showLoading: ko.observable(false),
        loadingMessage: ko.observable(''),
        loadingMessage2: ko.observable(''),


        initObservable: function () {
            this._super();
            return this;
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        },

        openMyList: function () {
            alert("Open My List");
        },


    });

});

I included this in the header file as shown below code in the default.xml file
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.my.list" template="ABCSolutions_MYList::list.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="my_list" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">ABCSolutions_MYList/js/list</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

In Header.phtml file added the anchor tag
<a class="my_lists"  title="My List" data-bind="click: openMyList" style="cursor:pointer;">                   
              <i class="porto-icon porto-icon-list"></i>
          </a>

I'm getting the error Unable to process binding "click: function(){return openMyList }".
Any issue with the above code? please help on this

In which file have you added text/x-magento-init code?

list.phtml file

You need to do all your code in the file you want to customise i.e header.phtml, put the text/x-magento-init code there and wrap the html you want to manipulate within a div that has the scope data bind.

Ok, Can we delete default.xml layout file? on this case

Yes, it's not required either way as you're adding the js component through text/x-magento-init

Let me know if the code worked or if you face another issue.

I will check and get back to you. thank you

@VivekKumar, removed the default.xml and included the text/x-magento-init into the header.phtml file. Still not working.

Please update your header.phtml code in the question

@VivekKumar, updated my thread. please check

Where in the header.phtml did you add the div you want to manipulate, is it inside my_list-div div, if not it should be inside it. Also text/x-magento-init code should not be inside my_list-div div ideally.

The ko functions you have defined will only work within your defined scope, you should modify the initial code like below;
 <div id="my_list-div" data-bind="scope:'my_list'">
    // all your functions will only work within this div as it is your scope 
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#my_list-div": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app":{
                    "components":{
                        "my_list":{
                            "component": "ABCSolutions_MYList/js/list",
                            "template": "ABCSolutions_MYList/list"
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    </script>

So, in short you cannot write the html you need to manipulate in another phtml file it should be within the the initial code and within div with id my_list-div

not working. however, if the script is outside of the div getting an error.

add your updated code in  question.

updated my thread as suggested your answer.
